# python scarpping telegram channel faster

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram

I want to scarp my Telegram Channel and I don't want to use Telegram API.
I wrote this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

text1 = []
time1 = []
x = 415568

while x>350000:
  URL = f"https://t.me/s/dollar_tehran3bze?before={x}"
  r = requests.get(URL)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
  messages = soup.find_all("div", class_="tgme_widget_message_text")
  for t in messages:
    text1.append(t.text)
    
  date = soup.find_all("time", class_="time")
  for j in date:
    time1.append(j["datetime"])

  x = x-20


print("len(text1: ", len(text1) , "|" , "len(time1)", len(time1))

df = pd.DataFrame([time1,text1]).T
df
```

But it's to slow and it spend a lot of time. How can i do it faster?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use scrappy . this gives you possibility to run concurrent threads to fetch data and improves the total time to scrap

Comment: thakns. i check it